# bootstrap responsive issue in 2 specific points

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

This is my bootstrap website: http://www.feather.com.lk/index.php

My main issue is in iPad portrait view. The elements are not resizing as intended. However, further investigation into the issue showed that I only have this issue when the browser size is scaled down to 768px and 769px. I'm not sure how to solve this issue.

The media queries I used:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width:769px)  
@media screen and (min-width: 770px) and (max-width: 992px)  
@media screen and (min-width: 993px) and (max-width: 1199px)  
@media screen and (min-width: 1200px)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like there is a mismatch between your media queries and the ones provided by Bootstrap.

```
/* Extra small devices (phones, less than 768px) */
/* No media query since this is the default in Bootstrap */

/* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) { ... }

/* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-md-min) { ... }

/* Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) { ... }
```

([Bootstrap Media Queries](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries))

As you can see here, the smallest Bootstrap media query takes a maximum width of 767px (notice that the next one starts from 768px). However, the smallest media query that you have used takes the width of up to 769px. That must be the reason why there are two pixels, where the website doesn't look as intended.

Try changing your media queries to be the same as the ones in Bootstrap.